# Disable read receipts on kik without jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, ios

How do I read messages on kik without sending the read receipt? Is it possible to do this by turning off internet connection while in the list of conversations and then clicking on one? If there is a method that does not require jailbreaking, will it allow me to view multi-media messages as well?

Comment: Do you mean Kik Messenger?  Have you been able to answer the question since you posted?

Answer (score 1):

i do not believe there is currently a way to do it, there are a few links on how you can do it one by one but as far as i know (without jailbreak) there is no way for it to be permanently set not to show read receipts (my friend has android and she has that set on her kik). sorry!